# How to find theme name in magento,just by seeing in frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I wanted to know the theme name of this magento site : http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/

Comment: do you have access to magento admin ?

Comment: i think your theme name is `forest_lingeries`. Because yur CSS files are loading from that theme only

Comment: @pradeepsanku I have access of backend. but the theme name is renamed by previous employee.

Comment: @Meenakshi the theme name is renamed. is any other idea?

Comment: check my anwser

Answer (score 5):

**Get Current theme name**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend');
```

Thank to [**drew**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445330/drew-hunter) for giving this answer. Check this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155570/how-to-get-current-theme-name-in-magento)

Comment: How the above line works? Is i have to check in that folder. I am new to magento. Thanks

Comment: Paste the above line in any one of the phtml files and go to that page in the frontend

Answer (score 5):

I think, you want to know the path from where the files are coming, I hope this may help:

Go to

> System>configuration>Developer{In the left panel in the end}

Then select the store view

In the main area

> Developer>Debug>Template Path Hints>Yes

Then save.

Now go to front end, your file with paths will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing usefull information. I set debug > profiler =yes. but i wanted to know the theme name.

Comment: Open any of the file in the code/community or local folder of the theme, in there in any of the file the author, copyright etc.. must have written

Answer (score 4):

Go to System > Configuration > Design > Package

[image]

and check above configuration.you will come to know from the above image.

Comment: thanks, i checked there too, they renamed the same theme as in the app and skin folders.